# Edit in place Meteor view without using Session

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I want to include a template (or use a helper, I don't care) that could be clicked to edit in place. This view MUST be reusable, and so can't rely on the `Session` variable or any other variables that aren't contained by the view instance.

In the display mode it would look like this:

```
<div class="editable">{{content}}</div>
```

which would change to the edit mode when you clicked on it, which would look like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{content}}" />
```

and you could revert back to display mode (persisting it's changes appropriately) by either hitting enter or pressing a button.

It seems meteor doesn't make this incredibly easy, since my first attempts with html:

```
<template name="editable">
    {{#if editing}}
        <input type="text" value={{this}} />
    {{else}}
        <div class="edit-thing">{{this}}</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>

// In the appropriate display template.
{{> editable stuff}}
```

and js:

```
Template.user.stuff = "yo yo yo";

Template.editable.events({
    'click .edit-thing': function(e) {
        this.isEditing = true;
    }
});

Template.editable.helpers({
    editing: function() {
        return !!this.isEditing;
    }
});
```

have had problems with not being reactive, which using the Deps library didn't solve. (This version just wouldn't change when you clicked it, since `this.isEditing` isn't reactive and doesn't trigger a change in the `editing` helper.)

Ask for more information if you like! Thanks!

Comment: This is a classical case when having access to the [`template instance` in the helper functions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/MWk_THcvfQg) would have made the task a lot easier and less hacky (no need to sneakily add properties to `this.data`, which is supposed to be *read-only* in `created` function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typical use case for Deps, did you remember to use both `depend` and `changed`? The js code may look like this:

```
Template.editable.created = function() {
    this.data.isEditing = false;
    this.data.isEditingDep = new Deps.Dependency();
};

Template.editable.events({

    '... whatever to start edit mode ...': function(e, t) {
        t.data.isEditing = true;
        t.data.isEditingDep.changed();
    },

    '... whatever to close edit mode ...': function(e, t) {
        t.data.isEditing = false;
        t.data.isEditingDep.changed();
    },
}); 

Template.editable.editing = function() {
    this.isEditingDep.depend();
    return this.isEditing;
};
```

Comment: Yeah you've declared the event functions differently than I did. I never had the `t.data` portion, I was trying to use `this`. Also, how would you use this in the templates? I'm confused by the distinction you've drawn between `created` and `editing`.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I looked to the documentation! Excellent solution!

Comment: @blaineh This is going to fail silently in browsers which do not allow extension of native `string` type (latest Chrome and Firefox). Consider using `Template.user.stuff = { value: "yo yo yo"; }` if you want to extend `this.data` in `created` function.

Comment: @musically-ut, could you post a source for that information? I've used this pattern a lot and didn't notice any problems. What is it exactly that would fail, and why?

Comment: Hey @HubertOG, here's some documentation talking about what he means (with the `data` being read/write http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst he actually has a point there. I'm testing it as `this._isEditing` to see how it works.

Comment: @blaineh "Variables and properties" section here: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/ `"Traditionally no error will be thrown when any of these actions are attempted, it will just fail silently."`. Turning on `"use strict";` will turn these into `TypeErrors`.

Comment: @musically-ut, so the problem is with the `Template.user.stuff = "yo yo yo";` part, right?

Comment: If the part about the "yo yo yo" is broken, it doesn't matter. That data will come from a context object in the real implementation. I'm just providing a raw string for testing.